# Какие man из systemd обязательны к прочтению?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, centos, systemd

Что Вы посоветуете обязательно прочитать из списка https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/?

Comment: Вообще не обязательны. Какие нужны для конкретной задачи, те и читаете.

Comment: По мнению Поттеринга — все!

Comment: **обязательно прочитать** - обязательно для достижения КАКОЙ цели? Для того, что бы сделать бутерброд с маслом **обязательно** нужны хлеб и масло...

Comment: мясистый списочек... по работе использовал толь описание по созданию сервиса для явка приложений. если вы не подлерживаете какой ни будь ЦОД вам не понадобится вся документация, читайте от поставленной задачи: создать сервис, изменить логироваие, усилить отказоустойчивость, добавить повидегие для устройство и тд.